# Python print function is returning a syntax error

Tags: python, automation, rhel, rhel6

I'm trying to use print function to print results of a re.match but it is coming back as invalid syntax for print

The python version is 2.6.6

```
import re

def word_replace(text, replace_dict):
        rc = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]\w*")

def word_replace(text, replace_dict):
        word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)",lower()
        print(word)
        return replace_dict.get(word, word)

        return rc.sub(translate, text)

old_text = open('1549963864952.xml').read()

replace_dict = {
"value" : 'new_value',
"value1" : 'new_value1',
"value2" : 'new_value2',
"value3" : 'new_value3'

}                                       # {"Word to find" : 'Word to replace'}

output = word_replace(old_text, replace_dict)
f = open("1549963864952.xml", 'w') # File you want to write to
f.write(output)                                    # Write to that file
print(output)                                      # Check that it wrote
```

Should come back and print results of *`word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)",lower()`* but instead i get the below error:

```
File "location.py", line 8
print(word)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `,lower()` .... `.lower()` and uneven parantheses

Comment: use `print word`

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing bracket at the end of

```
word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)",lower()
```

it should be

```
    word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)",lower())
```

Comment: Thanks, that has removed that error, but now i'm getting:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "location.py", line 23, in <module>
    output = word_replace(old_text, replace_dict)
  File "location.py", line 7, in word_replace
    word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)".lower())
TypeError: match() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Are you sure about this line `word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)",lower())` ?

Comment: In all honesty, no. I'm fairly new to all this. What would you have done?

Comment: You may want to try creating the dictionary in the function instead of using it as a parameter.

Comment: I thought I did that when i did: 
    replace_dict = {
"value" : 'new_value',
"value1" : 'new_value1',
"value2" : 'new_value2',
"value3" : 'new_value3'

}

Comment: The dictionary would need to be mapped, the keys are found in the left hand column. You could potentially be better using a different data structure such as an array if you have no use in the keys. What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
 word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)",lower()
 print(word)
```

into:

```
 word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)",lower())
 print word
```

Comment: That has resolved the original error, but now i get: TypeError: match() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Have you tried  `word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)",lower())` ?

Comment: Yeah, it says 'NameError: global name 'lower' is not defined' so I used .lower instead and got the typerror above

Answer (score 0):

```
word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)",lower()
```

this is wrong ,you forget to add closing bracket after quotes and use `.lower()` not  `,lower`

it should be like this

```
word = re.match("(0\w+)\W(0\w+)").lower()
```